# cronjob running every minute

Tags: php, mysql, sleep, cron

**Q:** Is it okay to set cronjob run script every minute or will it cause overload?
Reason why i want to run it every minute is:

Public script:
        * Client adds (for example:) advertisment
        * Script inserts data in mysql database (when = time + 2hrs, `activated = 0`, ...)

Cronjob runs:

        * Script checks mysql database, WHERE time is lower than `"NOW"`, `activated = 0` and takes that info, inserts it to another table, sets `activated = 1` when it is inserted.. (`activated = 1` happens in the first table (where Public script puts info))

So if this script runs every minute will is cause overload?  
If Yes:
     **Q2** Is there other options you could suggest (about chaning how the script works)?

Thank you!

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use the same table for both and just use a where clause (WHERE WHEN < NOW() - 2 hrds ) to lookup those entries that are "activated" (eg user had to wait till its seen?) just curious, because the cron can be a performance issue and will most likely run in vain in more than 90% of the time.

Comment: @Najzero it would be easier but the thing is that `"another table"` has Already so many entrys... and i would have to change public 'displaying' script..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every minute might be excessive, but it won't overload the computer. All you're performing is 1 `SELECT` and a few `INSERT`s. That should take a few seconds max.

One design change you could make, though, is that generally it doesn't make sense to copy data between tables in a relational database. You probably want to just reference the data with a foreign key, and use `JOIN` statements to access it with other information. In this case you wouldn't copy anything in your cron job; you'd just insert a foreign key.

Comment: If the system is already overloaded and these jobs start to pile up then there could be concurrency issues depending on what's actually being done (especially with mysql). In that case the system would have more problems than just this but it might be nice to program defensively in the first place.

Comment: Even in that case, the cron itself would be a pretty small portion of the cause of the overload, no?